# Using LEFT function to iterate through string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think I have a simple question. I want to run through pairs of chars in a varchar variable and check something. I tried to use this simple code (shown bellow)
but I get 'ho' printed twice. Why isn't the second LEFT works?

```
declare 
@name nvarchar(50),
@temp nvarchar(50)
set @name = 'house'
set @temp = @name
set @temp = Left(@temp,2)
print @temp
set @temp = Left(@temp,2)
print @temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx):

> Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number
>   of characters.

Therefore `Left(@temp,2)` will return "ho"

`Left("ho",2)` will also return "ho".

Therefore you will always get "ho".

---

If you wish to `PRINT` the first 2 letters, then remove them, you could do:

```
PRINT Left(@temp,2)
SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@temp, 2, LEN(@temp)-2)
```

If you are to then call `Left(@temp,2)` again, you would get "us"

Answer (score 1):

LEFT() function in SQL Server will only print the number of characters specified from the left side of the string. For you requirement, you need to use the SUBSTRING() function along with WHILE statement. An example is given below:

```
declare @str varchar(5)='house'
declare @i int = 1
while @i<len(@str)
begin
print SUBSTRING(@str,@i,2)
set @i=@i+1
end
```

Output:
ho
ou
us
se
e

Answer (score 0):

This is working exactly as it should be:

```
declare 
@name nvarchar(50),
@temp nvarchar(50)
set @name = 'house'
set @temp = @name
set @temp = Left(@temp,2) --here @temp has ho
print @temp
set @temp = Left(@temp,2) -- you are trying again to get 
                          --left ('ho',2)
                          --this will again return you ho
print @temp
```

At first `set @temp = Left(@temp,2)`, you are setting temp to hold `'ho'`. In the second set statement you are again trying to access 2 characters from the left on string `'ho'` this will again give you the same thing.